# yearly count total number of peoples who is frequently ordering atleast one time in a month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate yearly total number of peoples who is actively ordering atleast one time in a month.
but it returns 0.

**Try:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(o.CreatedBy)) FROM orders o 
WHERE 
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-02-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-03-01') AND 
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-03-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-04-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-04-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-05-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-05-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-06-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-06-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-07-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-07-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-08-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-08-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-09-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-09-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-10-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-10-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-11-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-11-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2017-12-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2017-12-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2018-01-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2018-01-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2018-02-01') AND
(o.CreatedDate >= '2018-02-01' AND o.CreatedDate < '2018-03-01')
```

Comment: OK. So what happened when you tried it? And what data did you put into it, for that matter? You need to describe your problem properly. This is very vague.

Comment: it returns 0, its a logical error, i am able to see records in database but above query returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.CreatedBy) 
FROM
  (SELECT O.CreatedBy, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(O.CreatedDate ,'%Y-%m')) 
  noActiveMonths
  FROM orders O
  GROUP BY O.CreatedBy) A
WHERE A.noActiveMonths=(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,
SELECT MIN(A.CreatedDate) FROM orders, 
SELECT MAX(A.CreatedDate) FROM orders)+1);
```